# "Cache" credentials on a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a bash script to run a few js scripts into MongoDB. Basically, what I am doing is, running the bash script and passing a parameter in this case called version, example:

```
./script.sh 1.0
```

That will go and execute all scripts for the version 1.0. Now, it is possible that MongoDB requires authentication user/pass, so I have an option in the script execution that will ask the user if it requires authentication.

```
read -p "Username: " mongo_user; read -s -p "Password: " mongo_pass;
```

My question is: what would be the best way to kind cache the same credentials to call the script multiple times? For example:

```
./script.sh 1.0
./script.sh 1.1
./script.sh 1.2 and on..
```

I don't want to type in the same credentials every time the script runs.

Comment: I had this problem too! What I did was use a perl expression to encode & decode the password string, then store it in a hidden file. This way the only time the password even appears is when you enter it initially. It gets saved encoded, then when you run your script you just supply it with the `decode(.pwd)` output.

Comment: Perfect, will go with this solution. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Dug up my code & submitted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caio,

As stated in my comment here's how I did it:
Thanks for Charles Duffy for the `printf` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

ePass() {
        read -sp "Password: " pass
        echo ""
        printf '%s\n' "$pass" | perl -e 'chomp($passwd=<>); chomp($encoded=pack("u",$passwd));print "$encoded\n"' > .pswd
        cat .pswd
}

dPass() {
        dPass=`cat .pswd | perl -e 'chomp($encoded=<>); chomp($passwd=unpack("u",$encoded)); print "$passwd\n"'`
        echo $dPass
}


ePass  
dPass
```

You can add these functions to your script. When you want to set the password ePass will do:

```
[KUBO@home ~]$ ./test.sh 
Password:
```

It will mask the input to avoid over-the-shoulder reading. Then it will echo the encoded output (remove after testing):

```
Password: Hello >>> %2&5L;&\`
```

Then you dPass:

```
Hello
```

So when you call your mongo scripts you can use the dPass output as your arg.

Comment: Thanks KuboMD, that helped a lot.

Comment: Note that `echo $pass` is going to misbehave if your password contains, say, a whitespace-surrounded `*`, and can also change behavior if your string contains backslashes depending which exact shell you're running it with and how that shell is configured (even bash will sometimes honor backslash-escape sequences without `-e` given, depending on how it's compiled, which `shopt` commands have been run, what the contents of the environment are, etc). More robust to make it `printf '%s\n' "$pass"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your addition. You mean the echo being piped into the perl encoding, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. BTW, `<<<"$pass"` (as opposed to using *any* kind of incoming pipe) also avoids that; however, it writes your password to a temporary file, which is something you may not want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks again. I'll update my response! edit: just noticed I named the string `dPass` which is identical to the function name. Seems to work fine but I imagine it's generally best practice to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

- The best way would be setting an environment variable and reading that variable every time.

```
comp@rangeesh:~$ export USERNAME=user
comp@rangeesh:~$ export PASSWORD=pass
comp@rangeesh:~$ echo $USERNAME
user
comp@rangeesh:~$ echo $PASSWORD
pass
comp@rangeesh:~$
```

- using the same way you could use the environment variable for a valid session or global var

Comment: Rangeesh, I thought about it but I also thought that the password would be stored in a plain text in the environment variable till the session is valid. I will see if that will be viable and think on a way to clear it up at some point. Thanks!

Comment: yes , after the script finishes you can clear it or exit session.

Comment: If the OP is going to use this, they would need to *source* their script or define it as a shell function -- not run it as an external command -- as commands can't modify their parent process's environment variables.

Comment: BTW, using all-caps `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` is probably not a great idea; all-caps names are in the namespace reserved for variables that modify behavior of OS-provided tools and/or the shell itself; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind when reading it that setting a regular shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable, so namespace guidelines necessarily apply across both.